# How can I decrease the space between my flex elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a header and in that header I want the margin between the social media links to be small while the margin between the home, about, policy, contact links to normal.

[this is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rDSj.jpg)

this is my html

```
 <header>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="social-header-facebook" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook fa-xl"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a class="social-header-instagram" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram fa-xl"></i></a>
                    <li><a class="social-header-twitter" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter fa-xl"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a class="links-header" href="#">home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="links-header" href="#">about</a></li>
                    <li><a class="links-header" href="#">policy</a></li>
                    <li><a class="links-header" href="#">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
```

this is my css

```
header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    /* sticky with top 0 make the bar sticks to the top */

}

header ul {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    /* when using flex and absolute you will need width % to make your items fill the screen */

}

header ul li {
    list-style: none;
    flex-grow: 1;

}

header .links-header {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.537);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    transition: .5s;

}

header .social-header-facebook,
.social-header-instagram,
.social-header-twitter {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.537);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    transition: .5s;
}
```

ps: I'm a begginer at css and this is my first time using flex anyway, so I'd be thankful if you point out any mistakes you find as well.

I tried setting a negative margin but that didn't work as inteneded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the HTML valid and leverage `flex-grow`. Add a class to the list items you want to adjust then use `flex-grow:0.5;` or a value that works for you.

```css
body {
  background: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/14/13/23/ocean-3605547__480.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  /* sticky with top 0 make the bar sticks to the top */
}

header ul {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  /* when using flex and absolute you will need width % to make your items fill the screen */
}

header ul li {
  list-style: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

header .links-header {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.537);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  transition: .5s;
}

header .social-header-facebook,
.social-header-instagram,
.social-header-twitter {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.537);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  transition: .5s;
}

header ul li.social-header{
  flex-grow:0.5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<header>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="social-header"><a class="social-header-facebook" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook fa-xl"></i></a></li>
      <li  class="social-header"><a class="social-header-instagram" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram fa-xl"></i></a>
      <li  class="social-header"><a class="social-header-twitter" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter fa-xl"></i></a></li>         <li><a class="links-header" href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a class="links-header" href="#">about</a></li>
      <li><a class="links-header" href="#">policy</a></li>
      <li><a class="links-header" href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

You could also skip adding a class and use the `nth-child` pseudo class, but an explicit class is better .

```css
body {
  background: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/14/13/23/ocean-3605547__480.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  /* sticky with top 0 make the bar sticks to the top */
}

header ul {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  /* when using flex and absolute you will need width % to make your items fill the screen */
}

header ul li {
  list-style: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

header .links-header {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.537);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  transition: .5s;
}

header .social-header-facebook,
.social-header-instagram,
.social-header-twitter {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.537);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  transition: .5s;
}

header ul li:nth-child(-n + 3){
  flex-grow:0.5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<header>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="social-header-facebook" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook fa-xl"></i></a></li>
      <li><a class="social-header-instagram" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram fa-xl"></i></a>
      <li><a class="social-header-twitter" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter fa-xl"></i></a></li>         <li><a class="links-header" href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a class="links-header" href="#">about</a></li>
      <li><a class="links-header" href="#">policy</a></li>
      <li><a class="links-header" href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to put the 3 "li" containing the social media links inside a div and give that div a width. This can be achieved using the below code. The shorter the width of the container div, the closer your social media icons.

```css
body{
  background:url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/14/13/23/ocean-3605547__480.jpg') no-repeat ;
  background-size:cover;
}


header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    /* sticky with top 0 make the bar sticks to the top */

}

header ul {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    /* when using flex and absolute you will need width % to make your items fill the screen */

}

header ul li {
    list-style: none;
    flex-grow: 1;

}

header .links-header {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.537);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    transition: .5s;

}

header .social-header-facebook,
.social-header-instagram,
.social-header-twitter {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.537);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    transition: .5s;
}

.social-icons{
  width:20%;
  display:flex;
  padding:0 10% 
}
```

```html
<header>
            <div>
                <ul>
                  <div class="social-icons">
                     <li><a class="social-header-facebook" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook fa-xl"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a class="social-header-instagram" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram fa-xl"></i></a>
                    <li><a class="social-header-twitter" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter fa-xl"></i></a></li>
                    
                  </div>
                   
                    <li><a class="links-header" href="#">home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="links-header" href="#">about</a></li>
                    <li><a class="links-header" href="#">policy</a></li>
                    <li><a class="links-header" href="#">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
```

PS: Please change your background accordingly. I have used one for demo purposes.

Comment: [Please note that this is invalid HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul). `div` is not a valid child for `ul`

Comment: to my understanding, html 5 made using div inside a ul fine so please explain why do you think so?

Comment: @PeterSamuel See the link in my comment: "Permitted content Zero or more `<li>`, `<script>` and `<template>` elements."  Run the code throu a vailidator: https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea and it will give you the following: "Error: Element div not allowed as child of element ul in this context. "